# Why is Array.IndexOf not checking for IEquatable like List<T> does?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, indexof, iequatable

Consider [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVgvG0) code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var item = new Item { Id = 1 };

    IList list = new List<Item> { item };
    IList array = new[] { item };

    var newItem = new Item { Id = 1 };

    var lIndex = list.IndexOf(newItem);
    var aIndex = array.IndexOf(newItem);

    Console.WriteLine(lIndex);
    Console.WriteLine(aIndex);
}

public class Item : IEquatable<Item>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Item other) => other != null && other.Id == Id;

}
```

Results:

```
0
-1
```

Why are the results different between `List<T>` and `Array`? I guess this is by design, but why?

Looking at the code of [`List<T>.IndexOf`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,612) makes me wonder even more, since it's porting to `Array.IndexOf`.

Comment: I wrote little post about this question: http://blog.rogatnev.net/2017/07/14/IndexOf-with-IEquatable.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementation of `IndexOf` in array class calls method:

`public static int IndexOf(Array array, object value, int startIndex, int count)`

As you see, it uses `object` as value parameter. In this method there is code:

```
object obj = objArray[index];
if (obj != null && obj.Equals(value))
    return index;
```

Classs works with objects, so it calls `public virtual bool Equals(object obj)` method, not generic one.

In `List` class `IndexOf` uses generic implementation:

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count)
```

So, it uses generic quality comparer:

```
EqualityComparer<T>.Default.IndexOf(array, value, startIndex, count);
```

**UPD**: I wrote a little post about this problem: http://blog.rogatnev.net/2017/07/14/IndexOf-with-IEquatable.html

Comment: This is why you *always* should override `Equals(object)` (and `GetHashCode` though for different reasons) when implementing `IEquatable<T>`. Very simple fix: `public override bool Equals(object other) => Equals(other as Item); public override int GetHashCode() => Id;`

Answer (score 4):

Because generic object collections use the `IEquatable<T>` interface when testing for equality in such methods as `Contains`, `IndexOf`, `LastIndexOf`, and `Remove`.

An Array knows nothing about `<T>` so it can't implement or use the IEquatable interface.

An Array instead holds objects that are not generic. It will call `Equals` to compare one object to another as all objects have an `Equals` method which you are free to override.

Comment: Isn't `T[]` generic?

Comment: Yes exactly. `T` is generic but Array is not. Array contains objects that are not typed. Therefore it will use object.Equals for comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` can make use of the `IEquatable<T>` interface, so that one works as expected.

The array is using the `Equals` method from `Object` and you are not overriding that one, but rather just implementing `IEquatable`.

Try defining `Equals` like:

```
public override bool Equals(Object other) => other != null && (other as Item).Id == Id;
```

That would work for both cases in the same way.

Comment: You can avoid code duplication by writing `public override bool Equals(object other) => Equals(other as Item);`, and this does *not* throw `NullReferenceException` if `other` is a non-null object that is not an `Item`.

Comment: Or yet `=> other is Item item ? item.Id == Id : false;`